# sort to highest rate codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

i have the average rating but how to sort those ratings from highest to lowest. My ratings table has only the id, restoid, userid, rate. other table is restaurants table

[Ratings table(database)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4fdA.jpg) 

this is how i got the average rate and was able to display it

> RestoModel(model)

```
public function getAveRating($restoid)
{ 
      $where=array("restoid"=>$restoid);
      $this->db->where($where);
      $this->db->select_avg('rate');
      $query = $this->db->get('ratings')->first_row('array');
      return $query['rate'];
 }
```

i have the sort of price from high to low

```
public function highToLow($cuisine)
 {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('restaurants');
    $this->db->where('cuisine',$cuisine);
    $this->db->order_by("cost","desc");
    $result = $this->db->get()->result('array');

    return $result;
}
```

> searchDisplay(view)

this is where the page the sorting shows

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!--<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/HomeController/sortresto/<?= $restotype?>">A-Z<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>-->
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Price <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/HomeController/lowToHigh/<?= $restotype?>">Low to High<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/HomeController/highToLow/<?= $restotype?>">High to Low</a></li>  
            </ul>
            </li>
            <!--<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>//<?= $restotype?>">Ratings</a></li>-->

          </ul>

            <ul><form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method = "POST" action = "<?php echo base_url().'HomeController/searchresto'?>">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="searchinfo" class="textbox" value="Restaurant or Cuisine" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Restaurant Name';}">
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="date_btn">Search</button>
            </form></ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a join & group by to get your result, Something like this

```
public function get_by_rating ($HighestFirst=TRUE) {
    $Order = $HighestFirst ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    $q = $this->db
            ->select('r.*')
            ->select('AVG(ra.rate) avg_rating', FALSE)
            ->from('restaurants r')
            ->join('ratings ra', 'r.id = ra.restoid', 'left')
            ->group_by('r.id')
            ->order_by('avg_rating', $Order)
            ->get();

    return $q->result_array();
}
```

Comment: yey thanks for this. It sorts all but how will i sort that to each cuisine? like i posted above for example, when i clicked the sort price american it only sorts price of american.

Comment: just add your ``->where('r.cuisine', $cuisine);`` & don't forget to accept it as an argument for your method.